# Azure DevOps YAML self hosted agent pipeline build is stuck at locating self-agent

Tags: c++, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, g++

**Action:** I tried to configure and run a simple c++ azure pipeline on a self-hosted windows computer. I'm pretty new to all this. I ran the script below.

**Expected:** to see build task, display task and clean task. to see hello word.

**Result:** Error, script can't find my build agent.

```
##[warning]An image label with the label Weltgeist does not exist.
,##[error]The remote provider was unable to process the request.
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: Weltgeist
Started: Today at 10:16 p.m.
Duration: 14m 23s
```

**Info & Test:**

1. My self-hosted agent name is Weltgeist and it's part of the
   default agent pools.it's a windows computer, with all g++, mingw and
   other related tools on it.
2. I tried my build task locally with no problem.
3. I tried my build task using azure 'ubuntu-latest' agent with no
   problem.
4. I created the self-hosted agent following these specification.
   I'm the owner of the azure repo.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

How do I configure correctly the pool ymal parameter for self-hosted agent ?
Do i have addition steps to do server side? or on azure repo configs?
Any other idea of what went wrong?

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Weltgeist' #Testing with self-hosted agent

steps:
- script: |
    mkdir ./build
    g++ -g ./src/hello-world.cpp -o ./build/hello-world.exe
  displayName: 'Run a build script'

- script: |
    ./build/hello-world.exe
  displayName: 'Run Display task'

- script: |
    rm -r build
  displayName: 'Clean task'
```

(UPDATE)
**Solution:**

Thx, after updating it as stated in a answer below and reading a bit more pool ymal definition it works. Note, I modified a couple of other lines to make it work on my environment.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
   - agent.name -equals Weltgeist

steps:
- script: |
    mkdir build
    g++ -o ./build/hello-world.exe ./src/hello-world.cpp
  displayName: 'Run a build script'

- script: |
    cd build
    hello-world.exe
    cd ..
  displayName: 'Run Display task'

- script: |
    rm -r build
  displayName: 'Clean task'
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You're misusing `vmImage`; it's not used to specify a self-hosted agent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using the self-hosted agent, you could use the following format:

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
   - agent.name -equals Weltgeist
```

Then it should work as expected.

You could refer to the doc about [POOL Definition in Yaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: Thanks so much for documentation reference. I've been really disappointed at how hard it is to find the necessary documentation to configure AzureDevOps pipelines; I just kept going around in circles, arriving at the same useless documentation. The docs for Github actions are so much clearer!

Answer (score 6):

I was confused by the `Default` because there was already a pipeline named `Default` in the organization.

Expanding on the answers provided here.

```
pool:
  name: NameOfYourPool
  demands:
   - agent.name -equals NameOfYourAgent
```

Here is screen you'll find that information in DevOps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and replacing vmImage under pool with "name" worked for me. PFB,

trigger:

- master

pool:
name: 'Weltgeist' #Testing with self-hosted agent

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware that if your agent only appears in the "Azure Pipelines" pool and not in any of the other pools then the agent may have been configured to be an "Environment" resource, and can't be used as part of the build step.
I spent ages trying to use a self-hosted VM for a build step, thinking that the correct way to reference the VM was by creating a VM resource from the Pipelines > Enviroments area:
[image]

The agent would be properly created and visible in the "Azure Pipelines" pool, but wouldn't be available in any of the other pools, which then meant it couldn't be referenced in the yaml used for setting the server used for builds.
[image]

I was able to resolve the issue, by de-registering the agent on my self-hosted VM with `.\config.cmd remove` and running `./config` without the `--environment --environmentname "<name>"` that was provided within the registration script mentioned above (shown in the "Add reseouce" screenshot)

Oddly, the registration script is a much quicker way to register an Agent than the "New agent" form shown in Agent Pools:
[image]

The necessary files are pulled to the server (without having to download one first) and a PAT with a 3-hour lifetime is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to update the self hosted build agents to the most up to date version from 2.217.2/2.210.1 to 3.225.2
As the automatic update for the build agents failed several times, I had to do it manually.

My Azure DevOps Server version is 2022 Update 1

After that, the build was finally processed by the one agent which was up to date.